# HTML5 <input type=date> change using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have `<input type=date id=something>`

I want change the data using javascript.

I am sending the query in mysql and I request for the date, so I need to put that date there I tried `document.getElementById.('something').value=$new` and it didn't work.

Comment: Do you know what the value of $new is?

Comment: Wait. Is $new a javascript variable or is that PHP? Where is your code loaded? When is it loaded. Is this data requested via ajax?

Answer (score 0):

Because the date format has to be in ISO 8601 format you might have to edit what you are passing as the value

eg:

```
<input type="date" name="dt" value="1999-07-16">
```

works but

```
<input type="date" name="dt" value="1999-7-16">
```

doesn't